Backwards compatibility of System.Threading.Lock
With the release of .NET 9.0, we have System.Threading.Lock which brings notable performance benefits over locking on objects, as one needed to do prior to .NET 9.0.
It is therefore recommended to use this going forward, but what if you are ALSO targeting frameworks prior to .NET 9.0?
I started by trying to use preprocessor directives, but it all started to get really messy.

Using preprocessor directives to exclude .NET 9.0+, you could create a compatible class such that when you're on any framework preceding .NET 9.0, there won't be any performance penalty over locking on an object, but when on .NET 9.0 or later you'd be able to enjoy the benefits of the optimization.
I have packaged this into a micro-library called Backport.System.Threading.Lock which is available for your use, leaving your code clean.
Source code: Github
Package: NuGet

Small update in the library now.
